# Combine checkbox and list in jqmobile

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, user-interface

Hi I'm experimenting with jqmobile for an app I'm writing. Love the inbuilt styles and functionality but can't find anything to cover what I hope is a fairly common requirement. What I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

[] Object 1 >

[] Object 2 >

[] Object 3 >

[] Object 4 >

( N.B. [] repesents a checkbox )

Clicking the checkbox next to an object name will check that box to enable 'multi-edit' functionality

Clicking the object name will trigger a separate event to edit just that object

Is there anything built in to cover this or should I just code / style my own elements?

Answer (score 0):

As of JQuery Mobile 1.2.0, I don't see direct support for this common UI list structure.  But you can come close with this:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="arrow-r" data-split-theme="d">
    <li data-role='fieldcontain'>
        <a href='javascript:void(0);'>
            <label><input type='checkbox'/>Item 1</label>
        </a>
        <a href='#'></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

See it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/x5fJW/2/

I'm not completely happy with how it looks. It's basically several clunky buttons and anchors sharing a list item.  But functionally, it works as I want.

For the functionality you want, you'll want to associate onclick handlers to the checkbox, its label, and maybe the li.  I'm not quite sure what you are envisioning with "multi-edit" capability.

I experimented with other list item arrangements, to make them contain a checkbox, label, and clickable arrow.  In all cases, I wanted to use a JQM arrow that would remain themeable.  But having the JQM arrow image inside the checkbox's label (so I could right float it) never worked.

JQM's enhancement process always covered my arrow with another checkbox:-(  Therefore, I had to revert back to this approach.  The benefit is that there's no hackery to be maintained (i.e. rehacked) for future JQM versions.

Although JQM enhancement can be turned off, it seems to only work a the page level.  I couldn't get it to apply to just one span element inside a label element.

BTW, I removed most of the form related elements that typically surround a checkbox.  That's because, I use checkbox changes to notify me to do something.  I don't POST their data.

I'm interested to know how JQuery/JavaScript wizards solved this problem, of making a more elegant looking list item containing checkbox, label, and clickable arrow.